# Why is JavaScript adding an additional non zero number at the end of the parsed number

Tags: javascript, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

When I run, `Number(123456789012345.12).toFixed(3)`, it is returning `"123456789012345.125"` as a String.  Where is last `5` (in the decimal) coming from?  I would have expected it to return `"123456789012345.120"`.  I executed this code on Mac with an Intel processor using Chrome version 68.

Comment: You are running up against the limits of precision of 64-bit floating point.

Comment: Do you have any document you could point me to on this subject.  but why a 5?

Comment: Floating-point formats are binary; .5 is `1/2` (well they're not *always* binary but "always" is accurate for most people)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#JavaScript

Comment: This is the reference I always point people at: http://floating-point-gui.de

Answer (score 2):

Your number is too long (has too many digits), it does not fit into the [64-bit floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) precision of a JavaScript number.

Below is an example of using less digits:

```
Number(123456789012345.12).toFixed(3):  '123456789012345.125'
Number(12345678901234.12).toFixed(3):    '12345678901234.119'
Number(1234567890123.12).toFixed(3):      '1234567890123.120'
Number(123456789012.12).toFixed(3):        '123456789012.120'
Number(12345678901.12).toFixed(3):          '12345678901.120'
```

JavaScript numbers are represented by a 64-bit floating point value.

It's not possible to represent the number you show using normal JavaScript numbers.  You would need to implement something like [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/).

If using bignumber.js then you can do the same using the following:

```
let BigNumber = require('bignumber.js');
BigNumber('123456789012345.12').toFixed(3):  '123456789012345.120'
BigNumber('12345678901234.12').toFixed(3):    '12345678901234.120'
BigNumber('1234567890123.12').toFixed(3):      '1234567890123.120'
BigNumber('123456789012.12').toFixed(3):        '123456789012.120'
```